# How can I work with camera cutouts and PlayerView

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a simple `Fragment` that has an ExoPlayer `PlayerView`.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        app:surface_type="texture_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_player_controls" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

This is what it looks like when I play a super wide video:

[image]

On the left you can see the space for the camera cutout. If I set the `LinearLayoutCompat` to have a background of some other color then it is really obvious that the `LinearLayoutCompat` is occupying the entire space, even where the cutout is. So why isn't the `PlayerView` taking that space?

I don't see any calls to set the `PlayerView` size, I just call `setPlayer()` and pass it my `ExoPlayer` instance.

Edit: I did another test. I put a view before the `PlayerView` and that view doesn't have the gap but `PlayerView` has a gap before that view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/amber_200"
        />
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        app:surface_type="texture_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_player_controls" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Edit: After a bit of playing around I figured out the widths of the screen and of the `PlayerView` are the same. So I checked margins and didn't see a difference but I see there is a padding. No idea whether that is coming from:

[image]

Doing this fixes my issue but I'm not sure if that is a good solution:

```
binding.videoView.setPadding(0,0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your layout file (xml)

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

And this in your Themes

```
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:targetApi="p">shortEdges</item>
```

Comment: I already have those things and the issue appears to be just with how the `VideoView` had some `padding`.

Comment: Check your parent layout Maybe you dded puddings to it